# "New release '18.04.5 LTS' available." message remain after upgrade to 18.04.5

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I just upgrade ubuntu 16.xx(16.04 or 16.10) to 18.04 by the command `sudo do-release-upgrade`.
The welcome message shows that I upgraded to `18.04.5`, but the "New release available" message also remains.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-209-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
New release '18.04.5 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Was my upgrade failed? How can I check my system is upgraded successfully or not?

Comment: Ubuntu Core 16 is a very different product to Ubuntu 18.04.5.  There is no Ubuntu 16, but the closest is Ubuntu Core 16, so please be precise & accurate; as you'll have problems as releases using the *yy* format are different products to those using *yy.mm* (Ubuntu having had releases using *yy* format since 2016; ie. *snap* only systems).

Comment: That was 16.04 or 16.10. I'm not sure which one was that.

Comment: 16.04 had two upgrade paths, to the next release (16.10) **or** to the next LTS release (ie. 18.04).  Ubuntu 16.10 had only a single QA-tested upgrade path, to the next release (as it wasn't a LTS release) being 17.04, so problems maybe expected for 16.10 to 18.04...  Stick to supported upgrade paths if you don't wish to *upgrade via re-install* in future.   I would `sudo apt update` & read the output looking for issues, then `sudo apt full-upgrade` to ensure system is fully-upgraded for starters.. A reboot & *test*, but what I'd do next if problems persist depends on what you upgraded from...

Comment: By far your best option now would be to do a *fresh* install of the latest LTS, Ubuntu 20.04. Will give you a clean and error free system, good for several years to come.

Comment: Did you reboot after the completed release-upgrade? Kernel 4.4.0 is a 16.04 kernel, not an 18.04 kernel. Review /var/log/apt/term.log - did the upgrader ask you any questions? If it offered you a 'partial upgrade,' that would be bad news.

Comment: Yes, I rebooted after the upgrade. As vanadium suggested I gonna fresh install 20.04, it seems that is the easiest way to go.